# Vertical line with arrow

Tags: html, css

Is there any easy way to do this kind of html

[image]

My version looks too complex for me, it is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/benderlio/kp9fs4yr/11/)

```
<div style="position:relative; height:160px;width:270px;margin: 10px auto;">
    <div style="float: left;">
        <div style="font-size:150px;line-height:100px;">40%</div>
        <div style="font-size:50px;">SOME TEXT</div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; height:100%;">
        <div id="arrow-right" style="
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);">
        </div>
        <div style="width:10px; height: 100%; 
          background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ec0c05, #ffbd5f , #13a854 );
          border-radius: 10px;
          "></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: this is more suitable for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .. your code is working fine and there is a lot of ways to achieve the same

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks, did not even know about the codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

You can set CSS Entity in `:Before` of `div`

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow+Condensed:400,600');

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #d4deea;
  font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #2F3F63;
}
#arrow-div:before {
  content:"\25BA";
  font-size:20px;
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative; height:160px;width:270px;margin: 10px auto;">
  <div style="float: left;">
    <div style="font-size:150px;line-height:100px;">40%</div>
    <div style="font-size:50px;">SOME TEXT</div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right; height:100%;">

    <div id="arrow-div" style="width:10px; height: 100%; 
      background: linear-gradient(0deg, #ec0c05, #ffbd5f , #13a854 );
      border-radius: 10px;
      "></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

For more type of entities you can just change content using
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_entities.asp

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```css
html,
body,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div.offer {
  /* we use grid layout and, depending on your use-case,
     define it as an inline element: */
  display: inline-grid;
  /* for absolute positioning of pseudo-elements and
      generated content: */
  position: relative;
  /* defining the rows and columns: */
  grid-template-rows: max-content min-content;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5vmax;
  /* defining the grid areas: */
  grid-template-areas: "hero ." "sub .";
  border: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 1em;
}

div.offer::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  /* to position the pseudo-element behind the content: */
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 90%;
  /* using a linear-gradient as the background,
     positioned at 99% across from the x origin, and
     0% from the y origin: */
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #f00, #f90, limegreen) 99% 0 no-repeat;
}

div.offer::before {
  content: '►';
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1vmax;
  /* while the top of the pseudo-element is positioned 50% from the
     y-origin, we translate the element upwards by half its own 
     height to position it in the centre: */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

div.hero {
  font-size: 4em;
  /* placing the element into the named grid-area: */
  grid-area: hero;
}

div.sub {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  grid-area: sub;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer">
  <div class="hero">40%</div>
  <div class="sub">some text</div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).
- [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas).
- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
- [`grid-template-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows).
- [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).
- [Pseudo-elements (`::before`,`::after`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).
- [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).